# How to access a list in a hosting Activity from an external AlertDialog

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, dialog, singleton

I have a recyclerView with a list of Competitor objects. The list that populates the RecyclerView is a global Singleton. In that Singleton's constructor I open a Json file, parse it's contents to populate the global Singleton's list of Competitors and use that list to pass to the RecyclerView's adapter.  Each list item has an ImageButton. This is what I'm trying to accomplish;
When the user clicks on the ImageButton (Delete Button) I want an AlertDialog to pop up and ask the user if they are sure they want to delete the Competitor. This part I have so far. But what I need to do next I can't figure out. I am able to update the json file that contains the global list's information but I also want to update the recyclerview by removing the Competitor from the RecyclerView by calling:

mCompetitorsList.remove(competitor);                      notifyItemRemoved(position);

However I can't get a reference to the mCompetitorsList variable from an external Dialog class. The same goes for calling notifiyItemRemoved(position)

What should I do? Below is the code for my Dialog class, my Activity that contains the RecyclerView and it's Adapter as well as the Singleton implementation.

```
public class MasterCompetitorsListActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String DIALOG_DELETE_COMPETITOR = "DIALOG_DELETE_COMPETITOR";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<Competitor> mCompetitorsList;
    private CompetitorListAdapter mAdapter;
    private SearchView mSearchView;
    private FloatingActionButton mAddCompetitorButton;
    private Button mDeletCompetitor;
    private TextView mCompetitorHidden;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_master_competitors_list);

        mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);

        /* initialize the Global Competitor's List for the recyclerview. Because this is a singleton
        it should initialize the list for the entire app's runtime
         */
        GlobalCompetitorsList.get();
        mCompetitorsList = GlobalCompetitorsList.getCompetitors();

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.master_competitors_recycler);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mAdapter = new CompetitorListAdapter(this, mCompetitorsList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // set a separator for the list items
        DividerItemDecoration divider = new DividerItemDecoration(
                mRecyclerView.getContext(),
                layoutManager.getOrientation());
        divider.setDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(MasterCompetitorsListActivity.this, R.drawable.divider_dark));

        mRecyclerView.addItemDecoration(divider);

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mAddCompetitorButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.add_master_competitor_floating_button);
        mAddCompetitorButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MasterCompetitorsListActivity.this, AddNewMasterCompetitorActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {

        mCompetitorsList = new ArrayList<>();
        mCompetitorsList = GlobalCompetitorsList.getCompetitors();
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {

        mCompetitorsList = GlobalCompetitorsList.getCompetitors();

        query = query.toLowerCase();
        final List<Competitor> filteredList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mCompetitorsList.size(); i++) {
            final String lastName = mCompetitorsList.get(i).getLastName().toLowerCase();
            final String firstName = mCompetitorsList.get(i).getFirstName().toLowerCase();
            if (lastName.contains(query) || firstName.contains(query)) {
                filteredList.add(mCompetitorsList.get(i));
            }
        }

        mAdapter.setFilter(filteredList);

        return true;
    }




    // *********  RecyclerView Adapter class *************************************************************************


    public class CompetitorListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CompetitorListAdapter.CompetitorViewHolder> {

        List<Competitor> mCompetitors;
        Context mContext;

        public CompetitorListAdapter(Context context, List<Competitor> competitors) {
            mContext = context;
            mCompetitors = competitors;
        }

        @Override
        public CompetitorListAdapter.CompetitorViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(MasterCompetitorsListActivity.this);
            View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_master_competitor, parent, false);
            CompetitorViewHolder viewHolder = new CompetitorViewHolder(itemView);

            return viewHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(CompetitorListAdapter.CompetitorViewHolder holder, final int position) {
            final Competitor competitor = mCompetitorsList.get(position);

            try {
                holder.firstName.setText(competitor.getFirstName());
                holder.lastName.setText(competitor.getLastName());
                holder.memberNum.setText(competitor.getMemberNum());
                holder.deleteCompetitor.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete_forever_white_24dp);
                holder.container.findViewById(R.id.main_container);
                holder.hiddenCompetitorId.setText(competitor.getCompetitorId().toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            holder.deleteCompetitor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {


                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    DeleteCompetitorDialogFragment dialog = new DeleteCompetitorDialogFragment();
                    dialog.show(fragmentManager, DIALOG_DELETE_COMPETITOR);

//                        mCompetitorsList.remove(competitor);  // remove from the global singleton list
//                        notifyItemRemoved(position);

                }
            });

        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return mCompetitorsList.size();
        }


        // ************* View Holder Class **************************************************************************

        public class CompetitorViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            public TextView firstName;
            public TextView lastName;
            public TextView memberNum;
            public ImageButton deleteCompetitor;
            public ConstraintLayout container;
            public TextView hiddenCompetitorId;

            boolean comptitorIsActive = false;


            public CompetitorViewHolder(final View itemView) {
                super(itemView);

                firstName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.first_name);
                lastName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.last_name);
                deleteCompetitor = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete_competitor_button);
                hiddenCompetitorId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.competitor_id_hidden);
                container = (ConstraintLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_container);
                memberNum = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.member_num);
            }
        }

        // ************ End of View Holder Class ********************************************************************

        public void setFilter(List<Competitor> newList) {

            mCompetitorsList = new ArrayList<>();
            mCompetitorsList.addAll(newList);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }


    }

    // ************* End of RecyclerView Adapter class **********************************************************

}
```

Here is the Dialog class:

```
public class DeleteCompetitorDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){

        final GlobalCompetitorsList mCompetitorsList = GlobalCompetitorsList.get();

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity())
                .setTitle("Delete this Competitor?")
                .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        // remove from the master_competitors.json file by overwriting the original file with the new
                        // global list
                        File file = new File("data/data/com.checkinsystems.ez_score/files/master_competitors.json");
                        if (file.exists()) {
                            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                            try {
                                String jsonString = new Gson().toJson(mCompetitorsList);
                                fos = getActivity().openFileOutput("master_competitors.json", getActivity().MODE_PRIVATE);
                                fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());


                                // somehow access the list from the calling activity to remove the item




                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                try {
                                    assert fos != null;
                                    fos.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }
                })
                .create();
    }

}
```

And if it helps to understand my code, here is the Singleton class

```
public class GlobalCompetitorsList {

    public static GlobalCompetitorsList sGlobalCompetitorsList;
    public static List<Competitor> sCompetitors;

    public static GlobalCompetitorsList get() {

        if(sGlobalCompetitorsList == null){
            return new GlobalCompetitorsList();
        } else {
            return sGlobalCompetitorsList;
        }
    }

    private GlobalCompetitorsList() {
        File file = new File("data/data/com.checkinsystems.ez_score/files/master_competitors.json");
        String jsonString;

        if(file.exists()){
            BufferedReader reader = null;
            List<Competitor> list;
            sCompetitors = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                jsonString = reader.readLine();
                Type compType = new TypeToken<List<Competitor>>(){}.getType();
                list = new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, compType);
                addCompetitors(list);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    assert reader != null;
                    reader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        } else {
            sCompetitors = new ArrayList<>();
        }
    }

    public void addCompetitor(Competitor c){
        sCompetitors.add(c);
    }

    public static void addCompetitors(List<Competitor> c){
        sCompetitors.addAll(c);
    }

    public static List<Competitor> getCompetitors(){
        return sCompetitors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple just create a constructor for the Dialog that you are using

```
public DeleteCompetitorDialogFragment(IMyListenerCallback listener){
     mListener = listener;
}


later on//
if(listener != null){
     listener.doWhatYouNeed(stuffToPass);
}
```

Then make an interface class

```
public interface IMyListenerCallback{
     void doWhatYouNeed(Object stuffToPass);
}
```

//then in your calling activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IMyListenerCallback{

      private void launchDialog(){
           new DeleteCompetitorDialogFragment(this).show(); 
      }
      @Override
      public void doWhatYouNeed(Object stuffToPass){

      }
}
```

Of course this is pseduo code and not tested, but hopefully you get the picture. Goodluck.